# Oracle modify global temporary table

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

https://community.oracle.com/message/15070384#15070384

Greeting Dear Community.

When we try to change the DDL of a global temporary table. It does not let us even the session is gone long ago.

Is this a bug ??

We are using GTT on a heavy transaction app with very high up time requirement.

So in real prd we would have issue if this happens all the time.

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production 0  
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0  
"CORE 12.1.0.2.0 Production" 0  
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0  
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production 0


Error starting at line : 27 in command -  
alter table TMP_REPAIR_TRIGGER_ANSWER add (ANSWER_PHRASE varchar2(4000))  
Error report -  
ORA-14450: attempt to access a transactional temp table already in use  
14450. 00000 -  "attempt to access a transactional temp table already in use"  
*Cause:    An attempt was made to access a transactional temporary table that  
           has been already populated by a concurrent transaction of the same  
           session.  
*Action:   do not attempt to access the temporary table until the  
           concurrent transaction has committed or aborted.  


Error starting at line : 27 in command -  
alter table TMP_REPAIR_TRIGGER_ANSWER add (ANSWER_PHRASE varchar2(4000))  
Error report -  
ORA-14450: attempt to access a transactional temp table already in use  
14450. 00000 -  "attempt to access a transactional temp table already in use"  
*Cause:    An attempt was made to access a transactional temporary table that  
           has been already populated by a concurrent transaction of the same  
           session.  
*Action:   do not attempt to access the temporary table until the  
           concurrent transaction has committed or aborted.  


Error starting at line : 11 in command -  
drop table TMP_REPAIR_TRIGGER_ANSWER  
Error report -  
ORA-14452: attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use  
14452. 00000 -  "attempt to create, alter or drop an index on temporary table already in use"  
*Cause:    An attempt was made to create, alter or drop an index on temporary  
           table which is already in use.  
*Action:   All the sessions using the session-specific temporary table have  
   to truncate table and all the transactions using transaction  
           specific temporary table have to end their transactions.
```

Comment: The error messages seem quite clear. A session, perhaps yours, perhaps someone else, has an open transaction which has accessed the temp table you're attempting to modify or drop. Find that session and commit its transaction and then you can proceed. Best of luck.

Comment: You might have forgotten to close the transaction (commit/rollback) that uses the temporary table. Should it be the case, the rollback-segment keeps growing too.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier solution for altering a global temporary table than killing all sessions that might have an open transaction on it.
You can simply rename the existing table and create a new one with your changes. Renaming the table works even if there are existing transactions running.

first

> RENAME my_temp_table TO my_temp_table_old;

then

> CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table ...

Comment: This answer is often easier, but it's also potentially risky if the table has lots of properties. For example, you may need to remember to replicate privileges, modify synonyms, rename constraints, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Global temporary tables should not be frequently dropped, created, or altered.  A global temporary table can be accessed by many different sessions, they only need to be created once.  The *data* is private to each session, but the *object* is not private.

(Your use of the phrase "this happens all the time" leads me to believe that you're constantly dropping and recreating global temporary tables.  If that's not the case please update the question.)

If you want to create a temporary table that is private to a session then you want to use a private temporary table, a feature introduced in 18c.

If you really need to constantly drop a global temporary table (perhaps as part of a schema deployment that automatically drops and recreates everything, although that doesn't sound like a process that would apply to production), you might want to look at the My Oracle Support document "HOW TO DIAGNOSE AN ORA-14452 DURING DROP OF TEMPORARY TABLE (Doc ID 800506.1)".  The gist of the document is: find all related sessions and kill them (which is also probably a bad idea in production.)

Comment: we are in the dev phase of a very complicated ETL job and the data model has been changing. we notice when the session is expired long ago, we still cannot alter nor drop the GTT. and in OTN SQL/PLSQL forum someoone suggests to truncate the GTT before and after our str prc. we are now implementing this and see what happens. and this is perhaps why we should use edition view in all our app...